# Upsert - using multiple duplicate keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using an upsert in my query below, and it works for the present day in terms of updating existing records based on 'extension' or adding new records if the extension doesn't yet exist in the table.

This query aggregates and updates total throughout the day, however, I need this to start over every day. So if the same 6 agent extensions are online for three days, their records will update throughout the day but we will end up with 18 records at the end of the three days (for historical reports).

The query below worked great yesterday, but now it's overwriting for today because the duplicate key is extension. I need it to update duplicates for the day using curdate and then start over the next day.

Any thoughts on how to do this with my existing query?

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, 
Total_Talk_Time_seconds,Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report )  
SELECT 
 c.extension as Extension
,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
, sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound   
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inboundambition_test
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
, count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
, NOW()
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
   LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
  ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
   WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
   AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
group by c.extension
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds = 
values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), Total_Talk_Time_minutes = 
values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), 
Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound)
  , Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls), Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), 
Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report);
```

UPDATE

Image of keys:

[image]

Comment: I assume your current unique is `Extension` (or `ExtId`)? (For a question about using multiple unique keys, you should add your unique keys!) Then you will have to change that and add the date to the unique key (`Extension, dt`). Without your table definition, it's unclear if you have a date column, so you might have to add it (maybe as a generated column). Just the date - if `Time_of_report` is `datetime` (including the time), it does not suffice.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, You're right. I've updated with a screenshot from MySQL WB with my table definition

Comment: Well, you need, as expected, an additional column with the current date (without time), so add e.g. the column `dt date not null` or `Date_of_report date not null`. (You can add data to it with `date(now)`). Your new primary key is `Extension, dt`. That was the easy part. For the other unique index, I am not entirely sure if it is correct. Is ExtId always dependent on Extension or can it change? So can you have e.g. Extension = 7295 and ExtId = 5 and then Extension = 7295 and ExtId = 9? If not, you can remove the unique index on ExtId, otherwise explain what should happen.